# Skrollr Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, skrollr

I'm trying to switch between images using skrollr and rails.  I've got all the files linked up properly, and I've had success with the library, but so far not with switching images.

I think it has something to do with the way rails asset pipeline works.

```
<div id="moves"
    data-anchor-target="#boxingRing"
    data--150-top="opacity:0; background-image: !asset-url(img_move1.png)"
    data--300-top="opacity:1; background-image: !asset-url(img_move2.png)"
></div>
```

My CSS:

```
#moves {
        background: asset-url('img_move1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
        height:295px;
        width:313px;
        position: absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        margin: -178px 0 0 -156px;
}
```

This loads the first image and increases the opacity on scroll.  However, the image doesn't switch to move2 at the break point, it just stays with opacity 1 on the first image.

I only have

```
    background: asset-url('img_move1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
```

in my css, although I've tried declaring all three images there, no luck.

The tutorial has it this way:

```
 <div id="moves"
    data-anchor-target="#boxingRing"
    data--150-top="opacity:0; background-image: !url(img_move1.png)"
    data--300-top="opacity:1; background-image: !url(img_move2.png)"
></div>
```

but the first image doesn't even load for me there.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I had my images in the

`app/assets/images` folder and loaded them via asset-url

For switching images, I guess it's best they go in `public` and are loaded via url.

This is an answer, but if there was a way to switch out images while keeping them in the app/assets/images directory, I would be interested to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: gonna hold off on answering this - I'll mark someone else's correct if I can keep the images in the app/assets/images folder.